# Converting Lambda Functions into Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am trying to combine a multiple selection with a lambda function into an lambda expression.  How do I do that?  I know the last line is wrong, but giving you an idea of what I mean.

```
Func<Event, bool> where = null;

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchToken))
    where = q => q.Name.ToUpper().Contains(searchToken.ToUpper());

where += q => q.Hidden = false;

Expression<Func<Event, bool>> where1 = q => where; <-- Erroring
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're really aiming for. Are you trying to perform multiple filters? What's the bigger picture?

Comment: The bigger picture is I have a generic function that takes Expression<Func<Event, bool>>.  I have conditional statements that I need to add or not.  I am using the Func<Event,boo> to build my criteria but want to send that to the generic function as Expression<Func<Event, bool>>.

Comment: I noticed something called Expression Builder, but is there a default way to do it?

Comment: You *can* build an `Expression<Func<Event, bool>>` from a delegate, but it almost certainly won't do what you need it to.

Comment: Note that building a multicast delegate like that almost certainly wouldn't do what you wanted even in LINQ to Objects - only the return value from the *last* condition would be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you want [`PredicateBuilder`](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx). (The source is available on that page.) You'd use it like this:

```
var predicate = q => !q.Hidden;
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchToken))
{
    predicate = predicate.And(q => q.Name.ToUpper()
                                         .Contains(searchToken.ToUpper());
}
return predicate;
```

That's assuming you want to "and" the conditions - you never made that clear...

Note that that is *not* a good way to compare in a case-insensitive way, either. If you could tell us what's going to consume the query (e.g. LINQ to SQL, LINQ to EF) we could suggest a provider-compatible way of performing a case-insensitive query.

Comment: What is var predicate = q => !q.Hidden;?  Is that an Expression of Func?

Comment: @MikeFlynn: That wouldn't compile - you can't use assign a lambda expression to an implicitly typed variable. You could either have `Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> predicate = q => !q.Hidden;` or `Func<Foo, bool> predicate = q => !q.Hidden;`. The first will give you an expression tree, the latter a delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx. How to use expression trees to build dynamic queries.

AFAIK when using Expression <> like that the expression must be known in compile time, because the compiler then build AST abstract syntax three and stores it as data in your Expression <> instance.